# how to create form in cake php

Tags: cakephp

I am very new in cake php, i want to know how to create form in cake php,please describe,when we go to create a form then what i have to do,like create model and controller everything

Answer (score 1):

In the view file, something like this would work:

```
<?php 

    echo $this->Form->create();
    echo $this->Form->input('firstname', array('label' => 'Enter your first name:'));
    echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => 'Enter your email address:'));
    echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => 'Enter your password:'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Save');

?>
```

In your controller:

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->User->save( $this->request->data );
    }
```

You can apply some sort of validation in your model, look in the documentation for that.

Answer (score 1):

Best option to learn about cakephp is it's own [doc book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)

But I'm providing you some basic code to create form :

```
$this->Form->create('ModelName');
$this->Form->input('ModelName.fieldname', array('type'=>'text', 'label'=>'Modified-Name'));    
$this->Form->end(__('Submit'));
```

Here `array('type'=>'text'...)`: `type` shows which type of input field you want.

`(...'label'=>'Modified-Name')`: By default it shows field text as `fieldname` but by using `'label'` you can modify your field text.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->form->create('controlpage',
                     array(
                       'action'=>'controll',
                       'class'=>'class',
                       'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                       'onsubmit'=>'return valid()'
                     ));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Block quote

Create form in html save it as ctp

> Block quote

And call it in view. `enter code hereUse cake php book to read further.`